# Referencing in c++ without passing by reference

Tags: c++, reference, copy

I have `class A` with a `public std::list<int> object list_`.
`Class B`, with a pointer to class `A a`.

In a method in class `B`...

```
std::list my_list = a->list_;
my_list.push_back(1);
my_list.push_back(2);
my_list.push_back(3);
```

I understand that my_list is in fact a copy of list_, which is why the changes are not reflected onto the original list. And for this particular area, I am trying to avoid passing by reference. Without having to do the following...

```
a->list_.push_back(1);
a->list_.push_back(2);
a->list_.push_back(3);
```

Would it be possible for me to directly reference the list_ object in A, without having to go through object `a` every single time?

Thanks

Comment: The better question would be why do you want to avoid passing references? You might be complicating the problem beyond what is needed.

Comment: Why is your `list_` member public? That's a design smell that you might want to revisit your approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
std::list<int>& list = a->list_;
list.push_back(1);
list.push_back(2);
list.push_back(3);
```

Basically I created a local reference variable referencing the `list_` member of the `A` instance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use *reference* as explained by other answers.

In C++11, you can do even this:

```
auto add = [&](int n) {  a->list_.push_back(n); };

add(1);
add(2);
add(3);
```

No `a->`, not even `list_`, not even `push_back()`. Just three keystrokes : `add`.

Comment: Though one shouldn't get too fancy with too many "local functions", one can easily confuse the maintainer with symbol explosion. Of course it depends, and of course time will filter out best practices.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you want to use a reference? Either this or a pointer is exactly what you want to use here.

```
std::list<int>& list = a->list_;
```

or

```
std::list<int>* pList = &a->list_;
```

Using either the pointer or reference means that additions via `a->list_.push_back( ... )` or `pList->push_back( ... )` will be identical operations on the same collection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like so:

```
std::list<int>& my_list = a->list_;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a reference?

```
std::string a("This is a test");

std::string& b = a;

b[4] = 'L';

std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
```

Here the `&` makes b a reference, so you'll see that both strings are changed by changing b.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to why you are averse to passing by reference.

You could add member functions to class A to handle manipulating the member list, instead of requiring callers to invoke the functions on the list itself.  I don't know if this fits your usage, though.